# R - set bucket from a mapper data frame

Tags: r, intervals, mapper, bucket

Probably a similar situation has already been solved but I could not find it.

I have a `mapper` data frame like the following

```
mapper
     bucket_label bucket_no
1    (-Inf; 9.99)         1
2  (25.01; 29.99)         1
3  (29.99; 30.01)         1
4    (30.01; Inf)         1
5  (19.99; 20.01)         2
6  (20.01; 24.99)         2
7  (24.99; 25.01)         2
8   (9.99; 10.11)         3
9  (10.11; 14.99)         3
10 (14.99; 15.01)         3
11 (15.01; 19.99)         3
```

and a vector `x` with random data

```
x <- rnorm(100)*100
```

I need to set the corresponding bucket for each entry of this in a quick way and `findInterval` and `cut` seem not to help for this issue.

Comment: The [mapper] tag description doesn't seem to match the question context and I don't find any package named "mapper" in CRAN so what is "a mapper dataframe"?

Comment: my bad, I meant simply to stress that mapper was my variable and x as well